# Intuition about inverse square fields from a mathematical perspective

Tags: vector-fields

Context: I'm a topologist, teaching vector calc this term. I was writing some exercises on surface integrals but was intrigued by the following:

The vector field $F(x,y,z)=\dfrac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} (x,y,z)$ is easily seen to be divergence free but not the curl of another vector field.

Related, the differential 2-form $\dfrac{x\,dy\wedge dz+y\,dz\wedge dx+z\,dz\wedge dx}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$ is a generator of the 2nd degree de Rham cohomology for $\mathbf{R}^3\setminus (0,0,0)$, as it is closed but not exact.

Is there any ''physical intuition'' behind this connection? I know that inverse square fields show up as common models for gravitational and electric fields.

Comment: Are you looking for the link between the 2-form and the vector field or a physical application of an inverse square field or a physical argument for nonexactness of the form ?

Answer (score 1):

The inverse-square vector field is not exact on the domain $\Bbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ in which it is smoothly defined.  However, if viewed as a distribution/generalized-function, its divergence is considered to be some multiple of the Dirac delta function.  More specifically, on $\Bbb{R}^3$
$$\nabla^2 \frac{1}{r} = \nabla\cdot (\nabla \frac{1}{r}) = -4\pi \delta^3(\vec{r})$$
and the inverse square field is $-\nabla\frac{1}{r}$.  The function $1/r$ in this context is also viewed as a distribution on all of $\Bbb{R}^3$.  The function $1/r$ can then be used to solve the differential equation in Gauss's law for any charge density by convolution.  Physically, this field represents the field of a point charge at the origin (the delta function.)